# Using glob to parse through folders for files

Tags: python, glob

I have the following example dataset output from pandas.

[image]

What I would like to do in an efficient way is using glob to search the filename in the associated main folder and sub folder only and not to loop through all the main folders/ sub folders as per my current code. I need this to then match against a main folders and sub folder I have and if it matches then it copies the file. I have code that works but it is very inefficient and has to go through all folders/sub folders for each search. The code is as below;At the moment, main_folder and  searchdate are lists.filenames_i_want, is also the list that I will be matching to. Any way i can make it go straight to the folder/subfolder e.g if i provided this as CSV input?

```
import itertools
import glob
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

filenames_i_want = Search_param
main_folder=locosearch 
searchfolder= Search_date
TargetFolder = r'C:\ELK\LOGS\XX\DEST'
for directory,folder in itertools.product(main_folder, searchfolder):
    files = glob.glob('Z:/{}/{}/asts_data_logger/*.bz2'.format(directory, folder))
    for f in files:
        current_path = Path(f)
        cpn = current_path.name
        if  current_path.name in filenames_i_want:
            print(f"found target file: {f}")
            shutil.copy2(f, TargetFolder)
```

Comment: Why do you need to use "glob" at all?  The dataset up above unequivocally identifies exactly 9 files.  No searching is necessary.  Why don't you just run through the rows one line at a time, and concatenate the three columns?

Comment: Hey @TimRoberts, thanks for your comment. Looks like i was over complicating it using glob and can just create a column with the full path name and then loop through this. Thanks for your response on this

Answer (score 0):

I created a column and used the fields to make an absolute path and then used tuples to go through each row and shutil to copy

```
TargetFolder = r'C:\ELK\LOGS\ATH\DEST'
    for row in df.itertuples():
    search = row.Search
    try:
        shutil.copy2(search, TargetFolder)
        except Exception as e:
      print(e)
```